# Move the alphabetical index under the tableViewHeaderView

Tags: indexing, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a tableviewheader which has a 2 segments UISegmentedControl. The tableview has an alphabetical index on the right. The index appear overflown on the tableViewHeader. How do I move the index so it does not overlap my tableViewHeader? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move the index downwards. It will always overlap your header.